# View is calling the wrong controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, view

In my solution "WebApp1" has two projects "WebApp1.Web" and "WebApp1.Api", in each project has two controllers "AccountsController" and "ApplicationsController" (same name)

In WebApp1.Web there are views:

In the create application view it's calling the correct controller WebApp1.Web.ApplicationsController

```
<form asp-controller="Applications" asp-action="Create" method="post">
```

Translates to

```
<form method="post" action="/Applications/Create" novalidate="novalidate" _lpchecked="1">
```

This is the correct behavour

But ... in the create account view it is calling the **wrong** controller ***WebApp1.Api.AccountsController***

```
<form asp-controller="Accounts" asp-action="Create" method="post">
```

Translates to

```
<form method="post" action="/api/Accounts" novalidate="novalidate" _lpchecked="1">
```

Its not suppose to post to /api/Accounts, its suppose to post to /Accounts/Create

**Question**

Why is the view calling the wrong controller? its not calling the web controller inside the same webapp1.web? How do I specific the view to use the controller webapp1.web?

Comment: Why aren't you creating links with e.g. `ActionLink()`?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core the "ActionLink" was replaced with the new TagHelper. I used TagHelper correctly, however the problem is I referenced a project that contains controllers with the same name - now the taghelper is confused.

Comment: Maybe try in the TagHelper - "MyNameSpace.Accounts"

Comment: @001 Not true, I'm using `ActionLink()` in my ASP.NET Core project. There I explicitly pass the name of the Controller and Action name.

Comment: Please check, Is there any route attribute in `AccountsController`.

Comment: ActionLink - form post?

Comment: Ahmar there is a route in WebApp1.Api, but there is no route in WebApp1.Web

Answer (score 0):

You can specify where to post a form in .NET MVC like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Accounts", new object { }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
     <!-- Your content goes here  -->
}
```